# How do I find the value of $\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}-+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I evaluate: $\dfrac{1}{1^2}-\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}-\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\cdots$?

Is the answer derivable?

WolframAlpha says the answer is approximately $0.915...$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A006752

Comment: Wonderful thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^2}$$ is given in terms of the generalized Riemann zeta function
$$S_p=C+\frac{1}{16} \left(\zeta \left(2,\left\lfloor
   \frac{p-1}{2}\right\rfloor +\frac{7}{4}\right)-\zeta
   \left(2,\left\lfloor \frac{p}{2}\right\rfloor
   +\frac{5}{4}\right)\right)$$ which can also write in terms of the polygamma function since $\zeta (2,m)=\psi ^{(1)}(m)$.

For a large value of the argument
$$\zeta (2,m)=\psi ^{(1)}(m)=\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{2 m^2}+\frac{1}{6
   m^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^5}\right)$$ makes that you can easily compute quite accurately $S_p$.

For $p=5$, using the above truncated series, the absolute error is $3.06\times 10^{-8}$.

Answer (score 0):

If (when |x|<1) and $s(t)=(1+t^2)^{-1}$ then $\int_{0}^{x}s(t) \, dt=\arctan x$. If we let $p(x)=\arctan x$ and $q(x)=\frac{1}{x}p(x)$ then $\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\cdots=\int_{0}^{1}q(u) \, du$. Let $C=\int_{0}^{1}q(u) \, du$. As mentioned by the user Andrei (before me) this is known as Catalan's constant. I can't comment further but probably Ramanujan's notebooks has other information about $C$.

I would guess, with current knowledge that $\int_{0}^{1}q(u) \, du$ has no exact expression (but as other users have said above) one can approximate it.